# Is there a way to simplify this matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I have 2 matrices A and B, where B is symmetric.

Is there a way to simplify the product $ABA^T$?

Comment: No, there isn't in general.  Is there some more specific situation you are interested in?

Comment: Yes, it was an xy problem after all, I have already found another way to solve it.